# Laravel can't add new option to the select using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

Hello guys i was trying to add a new option to the select using ajax but its not working and i have no idea why,,

```
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control multi_select" placeholder="Select category" required>

        <option> Op1 </option>

</select>
```

```
$(function (){
    $('.edit_click').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#editModal').modal('show');


        $('#category').append(`<option value="test">Test</option>`);



    });
});
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

i tried to use every code in the enternet and nothing was working but everything else is working in ajax

Comment: Please show full portions of your code. What element has the ```edit_click``` class?

Comment: it's just a button that make a modal popup and inside of the modal there's a select wich i want to add an option to

Comment: Please update your question showing that.

Answer (score 1):

Its working! It depends where you have put your code. It should be after the jQuery library loaded

```js
$(function (){
    $('.edit_click').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#category').append(`<option value="test">Test</option>`);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control multi_select" placeholder="Select category" required>
  <option> Op1 </option>
</select>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit_click">Edit</a>
```

Comment: but i put the jQuery library in the header and it's included int the layout how could it be after the code .. the code is coming after the header

Comment: Did you receive any error in console on click event?

Comment: No there's no error showing up, but there's a strange thing happening .. when i put the code that append a new option outside of the edit_click function and inside of the script area it works even though every thing inside edit_click function is working fine

Comment: Since you mentioned the Laravel, have you used @yield('scripts') and then adding this script in your blade view.

Comment: Yes i'm using it this way and the jQuery library is coming before the ajax codes

Comment: the strange thing is that it's working outside ot the click event even though everyting inside the click event is working fine